# If lower bound of a problem is exponential then is it NP?

Tags: time-complexity, np-complete

Assuming that we have a problem $p$ and we showed that the lower bound for solving  $p$ is $\mathcal{\Omega}(2^n)$.

- can lower bound $\mathcal{\Omega}(2^n)$ implies the problem in $NP$?

Comment: It's not NP but it is NP-hard.

Comment: How do you know it's NP-hard?

Comment: @user35734, it may not be NP-hard. For example, the naive (and I suspect optimal) algorithm for finding the a specified decimal digit of pi is exponential (relative to input size). However, I also suspect this problem is not NP-hard.

Comment: If you could show a problem to be in both $\mathcal{\Omega}(2^n)$ and in NP, you would have proven P$\neq$NP.

Comment: @kasperd: We call that Merkle's Puzzles, but it should be excluded from P=?NP because the specific form yields no other with the same properties *and* an otherwise proof of P=NP probably eliminates any way of making Merkle's Puzzles that actually work as intended. The exponential time Merkle's Puzzles is also PSPACE for the intended user.

Comment: @PaulDraper That does not work this way. There is (if P ≠ NP) a layer of problems between P and NP-complete problems, and it probably can contain problems which cannot be solved deterministically in less than exponential time.

Comment: @Joshua Merkle's puzzles are not exponential in dependence on *input length*. (Well, if we assume the solution for Alice is polynomial).

Comment: @rus9384: You are absolutely correct for a real implementation. If we allow the total problem input size to be exponential to the work required to solve one of the problems, attacking the merkle's puzzles is (exptime, expspace (which is >= pspace)) while verifying a solution is (ptime, linear space). Thus, producing a problem where the average solution time is most decidedly not P but the verification of a solution is P. Which technically meats kasperd's lemma but does not prove P≠NP. Building the problem, however, now requires EXPTIME so it's useless.

Comment: @Joshua Not only building, but reading as well. It would take "exponential" time for Alice to read the input.

Comment: @rus9384: In fact it does not. Never underestimate the bandwidth of a semi full of hard disks.

Comment: @Joshua Hard disks on Turing Machines? Nice theory.

Comment: @rus9384, you seem to be disagreeing with me. I said exactly what you did: there may be NP problems that are Omega(2^n) (therefore not P) but also not NP-complete (therefore not NP-hard). Naturally this depends on P != NP. I offered nth digit of pi as a possible example.

Comment: @PaulDraper Yes, it depends. But P != NP still wouldn't prove it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. For example, the halting problem has an $\Omega(2^n)$ lower bound, but it is not in NP (since it is not computable).

The nondeterministic time hierarchy theorem shows that any [NEXP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEXPTIME#NEXPTIME-complete) problem is another example (with $2^n$ potentially replaced by a smaller exponential function $c^{n^\epsilon}$).

NP is an *upper bound* on the complexity of a problem.

Comment: Could you give an example of a problem that is $\Omega(2^n)$ but not NP-hard?

Comment: You can construct such a problem using diagonalization.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. What is being diagonalized? Are we enumerating problems or algorithms? How does non-NP-hardness follow?

Comment: You enumerate both Turing machines running in time $2^n$ and polynomial time reductions, making sure that none of the former compute your language, and none of the latter reduce SAT to your language.

Answer (score 14):

No. First, as [Yuval points out](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/98279/9550), the problem could be much harder than the lower bound that you've proven.

Second, even if the problem takes time $\Theta(2^n)$ to solve, we don't know how this relates to $\mathbf{NP}$. It's possible that $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{NP}$, in which case any problem in $\mathrm{TIME}[\Omega(2^n)]$ is certainly not in $\mathbf{NP}$ by the time hierarchy theorem. But even if $\mathbf{P}\neq\mathbf{NP}$, it's possible that the problem requires exponential space so isn't in $\mathbf{NP}$.

The best algorithms we know for $\mathbf{NP}$-complete problems take exponential time but you shouldn't assume that "in $\mathbf{NP}$" means "takes exponential time" or vice-versa.